# How to add drive space alert on IP monitor?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, monitoring, windows-server-2012-r2, network-monitoring, system-monitoring

I am the administrator on a Windows server(GSNAPRINT) installed with IPmonitor tool. I want to add an drive space alert for another server (GSCTTLBACKUP) but was not successful.

But there were other file shares which were added to the same server (GSCTTLBACKUP).

I would like to attach the screenshot, but it requires 10 reputations to post images. I request the community to provide the same. After I log on the GSNAPRINT server web console and I click on "Return to Device View" where I am not finding the second option.

I am following this link https://support.ipmonitor.com/helps/649580d2e53d4207813667c9a7db0f12.aspx for configuring, but I am not able to find the second step as mentioned below.

2. Click the Monitors menu option, then select Add a Monitor.

SNMP services are enabled on GSCTTLBACKUP server.

Kindly help me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a way to natively do it via SNMP natively in Windows.  You should be able to do it via WMI, but I don't remember if IPMonitor supports that or not.  I would think it does, but it's been years since I've used it.

If you want to use SNMP to gather this information, I highly recommend [SNMP-Informant](http://www.snmp-informant.com/) Standard.  This extension for SNMP will publish most of the WMI counters as SNMP OIDs which can then be read by IPMonitor.

I also highly recommend getting [getif](http://www.wtcs.org/snmp4tpc/getif.htm) to help walk the OID tree so you can see exactly which OIDs map to which drives.

Comment: Can you guide me on using the WMI please?